# Upload Array having base64String encoded multiple images using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, alamofire

I am working out to send multiple images to backend using Alamofire. I have got base64 strings of images added in a NSMutableArray. Now ***I am trying to send this array of strings to server*** but its not working.

***I have tried uploading a single image by this way and it works super cool but why not an array of images***.

**Image Picking -**

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        {
            imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            imageView.image = pickedImage
            slctdImage = pickedImage

        }

        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        uploadImage(slctdImage)


    }
```

**Uploading**

```
func uploadImage( image:UIImage)
    {

        let pic :NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)!

        let str = pic.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

      //imageArray is declared as var imageArray = NSMutableArray()

        imageArray.addObject(str)


        //when imageArray count reaches 3 I send the images
        if imageArray.count==3
        {

        let parameters = [
            "task": "doNotification",
            "image" : imageArray,
            "select_category" : "exams",
            "select_type" : "quarterly",
            "class" : "1",
            "repliable" : "0",
            "select_students" : ["25","26"],
            "select_group" : "Super Users",
            "title" : "Hello",
            "text" : "asdfsdf",
            "date" : "2015-12-15",
        "time" : "10:50 AM"]


        Alamofire.request(.POST, UrlClass.baseUrl, parameters:parameters ) .response {
            (request, response, data, error) in

          // self.startParsing(data!)

            print(response)


        }
    }

    }
```

So how to solve this problem? Please suggest modifications to the code or else some other means.

Comment: Are you sure the endpoint you're calling supports multiple images being sent at a time? If it does, I would assume it would require them to be sent as MultipartFormData.

Answer (score 2):

use Following code to Upload image to the server

```
   let image = UIImage(named:"testImage")
    Alamofire.upload(
        .POST,
        URL,
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)!, name: "imageFile",
                fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        },
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.progress { bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite in
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        let percent = (Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite))
                        //progress(percent: percent)
                        print(percent)
                    }
                }
                upload.validate()
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    if response.result.error != nil {
                        // failure

                    } else {
                            // success

                    }

                }

            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
                //failure
            }
        }
    )

}
```

For multiple images

```
Alamofire.upload(
            .POST,
            urlString,
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "122222".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"Id")
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "test1111".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"sId")

                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "", name :"ContractorIds")
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data:date.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"ExpectedOn")
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data:date.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"ExpiresOn")


                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: data.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"Notes")

                for image in images {
                    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.05) {
                        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "file", fileName: "file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: You can send parameters by append to multipartFromData array

Comment: As well as can you mention any code for multiple image uploading.

Comment: Do I need to write any special coding in the back-end side.

Comment: Bro what is failure ? It writes use of unresolved identifier "failure" .

Comment: No need Abhishek, please check above edited answer for multiple images upload to server , you can specify encoding type also while appending parameter to multipart data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108155/discussion-between-g-abhisek-and-phani-sai).

Comment: As you can see I have a parameter as -  "select_students" : ["25","26"] .  But when i run the for loop to append the parameters it results in error "value of type NSObject has no member dataUsingEncoding "

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version as I faced problem in server side to read multiple images:

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        // Sending parametes with images
        multipartFormData.append(jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "parameters")

        for (key, value) in parameters {
            if let  files = value as? Array<Any>, key == "files" {

                for i in files.enumerated() {
                    let image = UIImage(named: "\(i.element)")

                    // add image
                    multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1)!, withName: "file" , fileName: "\( NSUUID().uuidString)" , mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                    // if you face problem add below lines as to make sepration between two images
                    multipartFormData.append("\r\r".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "")

                }
            }
            else { }
        }
    },to:baseURL)
```