# upload array of images with alamofire multipart

Tags: swift, alamofire, multipart

i upload array of images to server with alamofire multipart it uploades only first image (number of times array count) and doesnot upload the rest of images, i check every thing when get images from image picker to before and after appending image to multipart

```
extension profileViewController{
@objc private func UploadImage()
{

    let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(AuthService.instance.Auth_Token)"]
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        if self.ImageArray?.isEmpty == false{
            for (index, image) in self.ImageArray!.enumerated(){
                print(index)
                var imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.6)
                print(imageData)
                multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "photos[]", fileName: "\(self.RandomString(length: 10)).jpeg",mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                print(imageData)
                imageData?.removeAll()
            }
        }else{
            return
        }
    }, usingThreshold:UInt64.init(),
       to: "http://couponsub.farid.azq1.com/api/save-user-photos"/*upload_imageUrl*/, //URL Here
        method: .post,
        headers: headers, //pass header dictionary here
        encodingCompletion: { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                print("the status code is :")
                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    print(progress.fractionCompleted)
                    //self.ProgressBar.progress = CGFloat(Float(progress.fractionCompleted))

                })
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    if response.result.isSuccess == true{
                        KRProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    }
                    print("the resopnse code is : \(String(describing: response.response?.statusCode))")
                    let json = try! JSON(data: response.data!)
                    print(json)

                }
                break
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print("the error is  : \(encodingError.localizedDescription)")
                break
            }
    })
}
```

}

Comment: and on your server side it process right the photos [] array ? Also this is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499768/upload-multiple-images-in-swift-using-alamofire

Comment: i already check it on server side and i see the duplicate question but did not work so i post this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func uploadMultipleImages(imagesData:[Data]){
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        // import image to request
        for imageData in imagesData {
            multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "\(imageParamName)[]", fileName: "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
    }, to: urlString,

       encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in

            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: thank your for your answer it still upload first image number of time array count

Comment: check with fileName is not same for every file --- fileName must be unique everytime

Comment: Outstanding working for meee....